# Algorithm: shortest path between all points

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path, shortest-path

Suppose I have 10 points. I know the distance between each point.

I need to find the shortest possible route passing through all points.

I have tried a couple of algorithms (Dijkstra, Floyd Warshall,...) and they all give me the shortest path between start and end, but they don't make a route with all points on it.

Permutations work fine, but they are too resource-expensive.

What algorithms can you advise me to look into for this problem? Or is there a documented way to do this with the above-mentioned algorithms?

Comment: If there are only 10 points, then that's only 3,628,800 permutations. That's not terribly expensive. Are you expecting to do a lot of these?

Comment: 10 points was an example. We have to write a script that can take any number of points.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have a look at [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

You may want to look into some of the [heuristic solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution). They may not be able to give you 100% exact results, but often they can come up with good enough solutions (2 to 3 % away from optimal solutions) in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You can guarantee less than 2 MST in linear time.

Comment: Travelling salesman looks like what I need with the difference that it's not a closed circuit. Will have a look at the heuristic solutions. Tnx!

Answer (score 6):

This is obviously [Travelling Salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).  Specifically for `N=10`, you can either try the `O(N!)` naive algorithm, or using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), you can reduce this to `O(n^2 2^n)`, by trading space.

Beyond that, since this is an NP-hard problem, you can only hope for an approximation or heuristic, given the usual caveats.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this is an instance of the TSP. I think [Concord](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/concorde.html), developed at Georgia Tech is the current state-of-the-art solver. It can handle upwards of 10,000 points within a few seconds. It also has an API that's easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, actually:

[Floyd Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

> In computer science, the Floyd–Warshall algorithm (sometimes known as
>   the WFI Algorithm[clarification needed], Roy–Floyd algorithm or just
>   Floyd's algorithm) is a graph analysis algorithm for finding shortest
>   paths in a weighted graph (with positive or negative edge weights). A
>   single execution of the algorithm will find the lengths (summed
>   weights) of the shortest paths between all pairs of vertices though it
>   does not return details of the paths themselves

In the "Path reconstruction" subsection it explains the data structure you'll need to store the "paths" (actually you just store the next node to go to and then trivially reconstruct whichever path is required as needed).

Comment: Actually the OP mentions FW and it's clearly not what he's asking for.

Comment: The OP may have mentioned it but that doesn't mean he knew about the path reconstruction, which is what the comment above adds.